# Can I put Layoutbuilder into Listview in flutter

Tags: listview, flutter

I want to put `LayoutBuilder` into `ListView`, which means that there are several `LayoutBuilder` items and put them into the `ListView`.

I have used `LayoutBuilder` for each item because items have their own height, which means the hight of items are different.

For example

```
...
ListView.builder(
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
  return DetailPostItem(index);
}

 Widget DetailPostItem(int index) {
  return LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
           return Container(
               height: viewportConstraints.maxHeight,
                   ...
           )
        }
      )
}
```

how can I put items into the listview?

Thank you so much.

**Edit**

I want to iterate this item as a list.
However, a comment section, which is the upper part of the image, needs to be flexible in accordance with length of the comment.

screenshot is following:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: What's the benefit (or use case) of putting `LayoutBuilder` for `children` in a `ListView`?

Comment: That is because items for the `ListView` have their own height, which means height of every item is different. So I try to use `LayoutBuilder`. However, if there are other ways to assign different heights for items, I don't need to use `LayoutBuilder`. When I used `Container`, it is able to only assign one fixed height.

Comment: You can use `Container` for every item in your `ListView` and give them their own height.

Comment: How can I give their own height? because I need to calculate the height for every item. item consists of `CustomScrollView`.

Comment: It's bit tough to anticipate what you're trying to achieve, can you share some screenshot of your design?

Comment: I have added screenshot.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look once I get to the system.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me what's wrong in simply using `ListView(children: [Container("comment"), Container("image") ]`, I still don't understand your need to use `LayoutBuilder`. Simply use `Container` for all your `children` and don't give them any fixed height, just lay them up. If I don't get you right, I'll highly appreciate if you can show a minimal reproducible code of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Thank you for your help. Instead of using `LayoutBuilder` I solved this problem using `Column` and give `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,` function. I deeply appreciate your help!!

Comment: No worries, I'm glad you solved it :)